# ng serve not working even after updating Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular9

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the latest Angular CLI several times but cannot get ng serve to work (no error message). I noticed that my computer is running Angular 8.2.14 instead of version 9 but I cannot get it to update as well. When I try to update @angular/cdk or other packages I usually get a message saying the dependencies are incompatible (see error block). Does anyone have advice on how to fix this? I've tried every solution already on this site. I have Mac 10.13.6 High Sierra if that helps in anyway.

```
Node.js version v17.1.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for     production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 9.1.15 to perform the update.
✔ Package successfully installed.
Repository is not clean. Update changes will be mixed with pre-existing changes.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 62 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
              Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "7.2.16" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
              Package "ngx-mask" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">=10.0.0", would install "9.1.13").
              Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.2.16" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
              Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.1 < 3.6", would install "3.8.3").
              Package "ngx-mask" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires ">=10.0.0", would install "9.1.13").
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency typescript @ "3.8.3" (was "3.5.3")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/language-service @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "9.1.13" (was "8.2.14")...
Updating package.json with dependency zone.js @ "0.10.3" (was "0.9.1")...
UPDATE package.json (2387 bytes)
⠇ Installing packages...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" from @angular/material@8.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"^8.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/animations@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"9.1.13" from @angular/animations@9.1.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^9.1.13" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/Stephanie/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Stephanie/.npm/_logs/2021-12-16T09_20_41_953Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
✖ Migration failed. See above for further details.
```

Comment: `Node.js version v17.1.0 detected.` Not sure but could you try with Node 14.X ?

Comment: It didn't work for me but thanks for your help! @Emilien. I managed to upgrade Angular to version 10 but still nothing